# Populating multiple records from access form

Tags: ms-access

My company keeps records of job codes & purchase order numbers as machines are used, etc. I am trying to create a form where an individual can populate a job number and then input the time a machine was used (machine name and hours) for that job along with a few other fields. My primary question is if there is a way to populate one job code for multiple machines/hours. This would eventually be used for employee time keeping also.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating an *update query*.

See [Create and run an update query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-run-an-update-query-9dddc97c-f17d-43f4-a729-35e5ee1e0514) or [Update Queries in Microsoft Access](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/update_query.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure much of a newbie you are, but here's what I would do from start to finish.

1) Create an update query by going to Create -> Query Design.

2) Add your table to the query 
3) In the upper-left part of the screen, "select" will be selected.  Click on "update" to create an update query 
4) In your query criteria, add whatever criteria you need to make it apply to multiple machines or hours.  For example machines that have worked between January 1, 2017 and June 1, 2017 you would add (you need #'s for dates in queries)

> =#1/1/2017# And <=#6/1/2017#

to your date field.  Or let's say you have three machines named A1, B2, and C3.  You only want to  apply to job code to A1 and B2.  Under the field that denotes your machine name your criteria would be:

"A1" or "B2"

Whether you use the date or machine field, you'll need to use the update query to input the job code for all applicable cases. let's say you want to make the job code "Code124" for all people who meet the criteria you specified. Under the **Update to** line in your query, type in "Code124" and hit "Run" (the icon in the upper left corner with an explanation point.  That should do it.